# writing multiple lines to a txt file using R

Tags: r

I am trying to write multiple lines in a txt by changing a different value every time and create a new file for each change.
My code looks like this:

```
setwd("c:\\Andre\\")#set the working directory
parameter <- read.csv("Parameter_Distribution.csv",header=TRUE)
FSTDEC <- parameter$FSTDEC #the FSTDEC parameter from the table
KBOD20 <- parameter$KBOD20
x <- readLines("1.txt")
m <- readLines("1.txt")

for(y in 1:length(KBOD20))
{
  for(i in 1:length(FSTDEC))
{
  regexp <- "KBOD20"
  Lineno <- grep(pattern = regexp, x = x , value = F) #find the place that have the parameter
  newline1 <- paste("    1    3     ",KBOD20[y],"         1     0.101      1.15",sep='')#the newline for the replacement
  m[Lineno+2] <- newline1 
  regexp <- "FSTDEC"
  Lineno <- grep(pattern = regexp, x = x , value = F)
  newline1 <- paste("    1   17      ",FSTDEC[i],"         1",sep='')
  x[Lineno+2] <- newline1

filename <- paste("Newfiles\\FSTDEC@",FSTDEC[i],".UCI",sep='')
  writelines(x,m,filename) #generate the file with the new file name
  }
}
```

Now the problem is the writelines command, it should only contain one text and then the filename.
But how do I write x and m in the same file and save it as a new file?

Kind Regards,
André

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Line1 = "Line One of Text File"
 Line2 = "The Second Line of the Text File"

FileName = "TextFile.txt"

fileConn<-file(FileName)
writeLines(c(Line1, Line2), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Where Line1 and Line2 are your first two lines. You can put more in by just adding to this vector (ie c(Line1, Line2, Line3)